# issue installing git on redhat 5.6

Tags: git, github, redhat-enterprise-linux

I get the following error when run: 
It is somehow missing the perl dependencies, I am not sure do I need to update the perl or remove something as a workaround!

yum install git

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
The program yum-complete-transaction is found in the yum-utils package.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.i386 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.i386 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: git
---> Package perl-Git.i386 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.i386 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: git
---> Package perl-Git.i386 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git
---> Package perl-YAML.noarch 0:0.72-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(DBI) is needed by package git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(DBI) is needed by package git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(DBI) is needed by package git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.i386 (rpmforge)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Can you please help me solve the issue? Thanks,

Comment: Did you tried what the error message suggested? running `yum-complete-transaction`

Comment: yeah no help does not help!

Comment: yum-complete-transaction: command not found

Comment: ok check my answer and let me know if that is of any help.

Comment: Are you _sure_ `git` isn't available as an official package for RHEL? I'd be very surprised if so. Third party repositories might trample on the system packages, and get you into a situation from which it is hard to recover.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. It seems rpmforge's packages that git needs are broken. I had to temporarily disable that yum repo in order to download git correctly.

```
yum-config-manager --disable rpmforge
```

Then try to install git using...

```
yum install git
```

You may need to install another yum repo to substitute rpmforge, however I did not need to.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this repo:

```
 http://pkgs.repoforge.org/perl-YAML/perl-YAML-0.72-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm
```

and then run `yum install git` again.

**EDIT**

Try running `yum install perl-DBI` if you don't get an error then try running `yum install git` again. If you do get an error then you might want to try installing using RPM instead of yum, for instance:

```
wget http://packages.sw.be/git/perl-Git-1.7.3.4-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
wget http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/perl-Error-0.17010-1.el5.noarch.rpm
wget http://packages.sw.be/git/git-1.7.3.4-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Then

```
rpm -i perl-Git-1.7.3.4-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm perl-Error-0.17010-1.el5.noarch.rpm git-1.7.3.4-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Comment: Cau u pls let me know how to add it to repo

Comment: Try: rpm -Uhv `http://pkgs.repoforge.org/perl-YAML/perl-YAML-0.72-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm`

Comment: prompts me with this: error: open of pkgs.repoforge.org/perl-YAML/perl-YAML-0.72-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm failed: No such file or directory

Comment: sorry try again with the http:// part on front, check my edited comment above.

Comment: now gives me this: Retrieving http://pkgs.repoforge.org/perl-YAML/perl-YAML-0.72-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm
error: skipping http://pkgs.repoforge.org/perl-YAML/perl-YAML-0.72-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error

Comment: !! why is this happening man?! how come its too hard to install a thing on linux!

Comment: let's try something different. Run `yum install perl-DBI` first and tell me what you get.

Comment: Simple: Install non-official stuff, get a mangled system.

Comment: Install `yum-utils`, delete the non-official repos, run `package-cleanup --orphans`, delete all that. So you will have a clean(er) slate. Install the EPEL repository (they are _very_ careful not to step on the instaled system) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use yum on a Red Hat/Oracle Linux server which says "This system is not registered with RHN.", there is a wonderful option to add the free yum repository.

Read about licensing and Red Hat/Oracle Linux here:
http://flashdba.com/2012/10/08/this-system-is-not-registered-with-uln-rhn/

Read how to add the Public Yum Server here:
http://public-yum.oracle.com/

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
yum --nogpgcheck install git -y
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.